# Netsuite SuiteScript set custom segment value on sales order

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, restlet, suitescript1.0

I can create a Netsuite sales order record using SuiteScript 2 and JavaScript. I am unable to find the field I need to set in order to set a custom segment value for my sales order. I am looking for help with this.

My custom segment is called Revenue Channel and I can see it associated with a sales order. I can see my custom segments's ID (cseg1) and Record ID (customrecord_cseg1) on the custom segments page in Netsuite. When I view a Sales Order in Netsuite's UI, I can only see the Revenue Channel custom segment when I change my form to an alternate form, like my Standard Sales Order form.

After I set this field in the UI, if I do a SuiteScript JavaScript search for this sales order, I am able to print (console log) every field on the sales order record, but my custom segment field does not show up. I am not sure how to find it so I can set its value when I create a new one programmatically.

Does anyone know how to set a custom segment value for a sales order record programmatically using JavaScript?

For example, this code below will print all of the fields of my sales order that I know has a custom segment (Revenue Channel) value set in the UI. I am unable to find this field on this sales order object.

```
require(['N/search', 'N/record'], function(search, record){
  var nsSalesOrderIds = []
  search
    .create({
      type: search.Type.SALES_ORDER,
      filters: [
        search.createFilter({
          name: 'internalid', // 'internalid' 'tranid'
          operator: search.Operator.IS,
          values: 123,
        }),
      ],
    })
    .run()
    .each(function (result) {
      console.log(result.toJSON())
      if (result.id) nsSalesOrderIds.push(result.id)
    })
    console.log(nsSalesOrderIds)

    var objRecord = record.load({
      type: search.Type.SALES_ORDER,
      id: nsSalesOrderIds[0],
      columns: 'itemid'
    });

    var objFields = objRecord.getFields();

    var emptyFields = []
    for (var i = 0; i < objFields.sort().length; i++) {
      var val = objRecord.getValue({
        fieldId: objFields[i]
      });
      console.log(objFields[i] + ' = ' + val)
    }

    var sublistName = objRecord.getSublists();
    console.log(sublistName.sort())

    var itemFields = objRecord.getSublistFields({
        sublistId: 'item'
    });
    console.log(itemFields.sort())        
})
```

This code below is how I can create a sales order, but I have not figured out how to save the custom segment for it.

```
  try {
    var salesOrder = record.create({
      type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
      isDynamic: true,
      defaultValues: {
        entity: 123,
      },
    });

    salesOrder.setValue({
      fieldId: 'location',
      value: 3123,
    })

    salesOrder.setText({
      fieldId: "datecreated",
      text: "7/18/2022",
    });

    // Setting custom segment here does 
    // not work but it does not error either.
    salesOrder.setText({
      fieldId: 'cseg1',
      text: 'My Custom Value',
      ignoreFieldChange: true
    })

    // This does not work either.
    salesOrder.setValue({
      fieldId: 'cseg1',
      value: 1,
    })

    // Set item specific
    salesOrder.selectNewLine({
      sublistId: 'item'
    });

    salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
      sublistId: 'item',
      fieldId: 'item',
      value: 2121
    });

    salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
      sublistId: 'item',
      fieldId: 'quantity',
      value: 1
    });

    salesOrder.commitLine({
      sublistId: 'item'
    });

    var newSalesOrderId = salesOrder.save();
    console.log('newSalesOrderId', newSalesOrderId)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.toJSON())
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom segment value is saved on another form. In my example, that form is ID = 23. In order to get access to that 'cseg1' field, I need to include the form in with the defaultValues when I create my sales order. See my code below.

```
var salesOrder = record.create({
  type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
  isDynamic: true,
  defaultValues: {
    entity: 123,    
    customForm: 23,
  },
})

// Either way works, you don't need both
salesOrder.setValue{
  fieldId: 'cseg1',
  value: 1,
})

// Either way works, you don't need both
salesOrder.setText({
  fieldId: 'cseg1',
  text: 'Some String',
})
```