# NetSuite Set Custom Segment Value on Vendor Bill

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0, restlet-2.0

UPDATE: It's a Permission issue for Custom Role which I am using to execute the Restlet. Any idea which set of Lists/Setup/Transactions/Custom-Record to add on the Permission

I have a Custom Segment called Program, and the label for it on Netsuite is "cseg_program" which is one of the inputs in the Key, and the value is the internal ID associated with it. However, the code below still does not populate the data in the expense section. I am unsure if there are any restrictions around it as I do not see anything specific in the error logs.

Code changes made based on the : [Question-73028265](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028265/netsuite-suitescript-set-custom-segment-value-on-sales-order)
Below is the snippet that creates the Expense data for the Vendor Bill.

```
 function buildBasicVendorRecord(reqBody) {
      // Creating Vendor Bill
      try {
        var VendorBill = record.create({
          type: record.Type.VENDOR_BILL,
          isDynamic: true,
          defaultValues: {
            entity: 123,
            customForm: 50,
          }
        });
        log.debug("Created vendor Bill :",VendorBill);

        reqBody.lines.forEach(function (line, i) {
          VendorBill.selectNewLine({
            sublistId: "expense",
          });
          for (var key in line) {
            if (!Utils.isNullOrEmpty(line)) {
              log.debug("Key 2:",key);
              log.debug("Value 2:",line[key]);
              VendorBill.setCurrentSublistValue({
                sublistId: "expense",
                fieldId: key,
                value: line[key],
              });
            }
          }
 
          VendorBill.commitLine({
            sublistId: "expense",
          });
        });
        log.debug("vendorBill after commitlines :", VendorBill);
        return VendorBill;
      } catch (e) {
        log.debug("Error value from here is :",e);
        throw e;
      }
    }
```

Comment: For the new Expense lines, the order in which you are setting key /line[key] might matter.  There is also a "forceSyncSourcing" parameter you might want to set to true.  Can reference https://suiteanswers.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/45404.  Ex: in my environment on the Expense line, in the UI and via script I must set Expense Category first then then Account, Dept, Location, Class is set/sourced.  Only after they are set/sourced can I change the values for i.e. Dept.

Comment: Actually, everything else is working as expected, its the Custom Segment ie "cseg_program" which is the only element that is getting skipped, I could see within the logs that the Expense -> currentLine is holding the same field Id and the value which is set via code, but at the end of the "commitline" something goes wrong.

Comment: Well, you are right about the order of setting these values, But in this specific case, I do not have any validations or filters based on the selection made previously that could affect the current field selection. And so far the know/existing segments are set to the exact values only this custom segment is not getting set. To add more about my current analysis would be, there is something happening within the "VendorBill.commitLine({
            sublistId: "expense",
          });
        });"
I added logs before and after the commitline, and I do not see the custom segment value assigned